# Chrome show errors "Your connection is not private"

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, settings

Yesterday I update Chrome browser on my Ubuntu 14.04 as they are suggested to me.

Now I can not access following web sites: 
google.com, youtube.com and gmail.com

and the error is

> **Your connection is not private**
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.google.rs
>   (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>   NET::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM

I reinstall chrom, clear all data but nothing... all I can found on google(from firefox) are old posts ...

Does anyone know how to solve this?

*Note: I can access to the rest of the web - regular web sites, but can not to the google services/web sites.*

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing the [Network Security Service libraries package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnss3-1d) with

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d
```

solved it for me.

Comment: could you explain what the package is and how it solved the problem?

Comment: There is a bit more information needed around your 'to the point' answer.

Comment: Thanks Zanna and Elder, for the corrections. It was my first post. Next time it will be better

Answer (score 3):

First add following to your sources.list

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
```

Then Run

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d
```

It worked for me.

Comment: on ubuntu 18.04
 Package 'libnss3-1d' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment yet but I'll provide you what I know. The .deb file provided by Google for their Chrome installer mislabeled the libnss3 installed already as 'equal or higher' (Version in 14.04 is 2:3.26.2-really.3.15.4 which is 2.3.15.4 labeled as 2.3.26.2) which is why during update it didn't download the needed dependency updates. Soo.. Google chrome is having problems verifying the SSL encryption due to the outdated library.

Well actually Google Chrome isn't the only one affected by that, I think all Chromium based browsers where affected by this issue (A bit earlier than what happened to Chrome 57 too).

Steam's web browser had a certificate issues a bit earlier (I think like since last year) too and manually installing libnss3-1d fixed the problem