# Privacy error on Ubuntu 20.04LTS when loading webpages

Tags: 20.04, firefox, google-chrome

I am running Ubuntu 20.04LTS on a VirtualBox virtual machine. When I try and load github, for example it displays the error message:

**In Chromium**

[Error message on Chromium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMOLy.png)

**In Firefox**

[Error message in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSkEo.png)

This happens whether I'm using Chromium or Firefoxn inside the VM, so I assume it is unrelated to browsers. When I load github from the Windows machine, no errors occur.

I have tried installing `libnss3` as was recommended on [this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890988/chrome-show-errors-your-connection-is-not-private). I could not find `libnss3-id` for my system on [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libnss3/download).

I installed both `libnss3` and `libnss3-dev` using `aptitude` and `apt-get`, respectively. The issue has still not been resolved.

Comment: From your error messages, it looks like there's something sitting **above** your VM that acts as a man-in-the-middle and replaces the certificates on HTTPS sites with its own certificates. It may be some kind of proxy. It may be sitting on your host OS (maybe your antivirus, or a part of virtualization software?) or on the network, between your machine and the Internet. You can probably connect from your host OS because this "thing" has added its certificate to your browsers, but that doesn't apply for VM. You have to look for this "thing", but **outside** of your VM.

Comment: Thanks for this, @raj. This seems to be the most likely reason, since I'm using a laptop with a VPN installed and running.

Comment: You can look for certificates that the VPN software probably installed into your host OS browser, export them and manually install into browsers on your VM, then you probably should be able to connect.